How to use SortBy in Dynamic Mudtable
I am creating MudTab with MudTable .The columns and data are passed dynamically to the MudTab and  MudTable. But I cannot figure it out  how to set
<MudTh><MudTableSortLabel SortBy</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
    Tab.razor
    <MudTabs  @bind-ActivePanelIndex="_index">
    <ChildContent>
    @foreach (var tab in tabs)
    {
    <MudTabPanel Text="@tab.Text">
    <MudTable Items="@tab.TableData" Hover="true">          
    <HeaderContent>
     @foreach (var column in tab.ColumnNames)
     {
     <MudTh>                                 
      @column 
     </MudTh>
     }
     </HeaderContent> 
     <RowTemplate>
     @foreach (var column in tab.ColumnNames)
     {
     <MudTd DataLabel="@column">@context.GetDisplayValue(column)</MudTd>
     }
     </RowTemplate>
     </MudTable>
     </MudTabPanel>
      }
    </ChildContent>

   </MudTabs>

    Tab.razor.cs
    public partial class Tab
    {
    public interface ITableData
    {
    string GetDisplayValue(string propertyName);
    object GetSortValue(string propertyName);
    }
    public class TabModel 
    {
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public List<string> ColumnNames { get; set; } = new();
    public List<ITableData> TableData { get; set; } = new();         
    }       

    public class All : ITableData
    {
    public string Field1 { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Field2 { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string GetDisplayValue(string propertyName)
    {
    return propertyName switch
    {
    "Field1" => Field1 ,
    "Field2" => Field2 
    };
    }
    public object GetSortValue(string propertyName)
    {
    return propertyName switch
    {
    "Field1" => Field1,
    "Field2" => Field2,
    _ => string.Empty,
    };
    }
    }
    public class Net  : ITableData
    {
    public string NetField1 { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string NetField2 { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string GetDisplayValue(string propertyName)
    {
    return propertyName switch
    {
    "NetField1" => NetField1 ,
    "NetField2" => NetField2 ,               
     _ => string.Empty,
    };
    }
    public object GetSortValue(string propertyName)
    {
    return propertyName switch
    {
    "NetField1" => NetField1 ,
    "NetField2" => NetField2 ,               
    _ => string.Empty
     };
     }
     }
    private int _index = 0;      
    private int? _nextIndex = null;
    private int selectedIndex = 0;
    private List<TabModel> tabs = new();
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
    base.OnInitialized();
    tabs = new List<TabModel>
    {
    new TabModel
    {
    Index = 0,
    Text = "All",
    ColumnNames = new List<string> { "Field1", "Field1"},
    TableData = new List<ITableData>
    {
    new All { Field1 = "Name1",Field2 ="125KB" },
    new All {  Field1 = "Name2", Field2 ="125KB" }
    } 
    },
    new TabModel
    {
    Index = 1,
    Text = "Net",
    ColumnNames = new List<string> { "NetField1", "NetField2"},
    TableData = new List<ITableData>
    {
    new Net { NetField1 = "25%" , NetField2 = "Process1" },
    new Net { NetField1 = "35%" , NetField2 = "Process2" }
    }  
    }; 
    }     
 }

I tried  the following options
 <MudTableSortLabel SortBy="((object)(column))">@column</MudTableSortLabel>
    <MudTableSortLabel SortBy="@(context => context.GetSortValue(column))">
    <MudTableSortLabel SortBy="@(x => x.GetSortValue(column))">
        @column
    </MudTableSortLabel>


And tried other options too. but nothing worked out. Getting error asking to enter the T explicitly
for Funct<T,object>
How do I add the Class name

IMO you shouldn't do this. Stick to creating an element for each property. You'll save yourself more headache down the line.

If you know your Type T and you have a SortLabel and a SortHeader you can do it like this:
Note: config is a custom class, you have to get it from somewhere in your code - SortLabel and SortHeader are just strings.
<MudTableSortLabel SortLabel="@config.Sortlabel" T="YourType">
     @config.SortHeader
</MudTableSortLabel>

Edit
If you have a simple scenario I would just go with this solution.
Otherwise it would become very complicated.
If you want to go with the dynamic solution, you should consider the following:

Think about having server side pagination and sorting and filtering
Restructure your component to have only the MudTable in it - no tabs or something else
I´m building a nuget package which addresses exact this use case: Server side pagination, sorting and filtering with MudTable in Blazor. Coming soon. You would need this package at the server side.
Set on MudTable AllowUnsorted="false" to disable the third state


When I  am looping through multiple classes  how do I get the T? Can you suggest any general way  to find that . I  may have 3-4 classes each one for tab content. I have Class Names Like  CLass A , ClassB , Class C etc..

I think the  T Parameter can not be set by a variable. If you have only 3-4 classes you might just use an if/else  statement and set T to a concrete value like ClassA etc.

I get null reference exception after adding the 

@column



https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/mYcoEgcxUbRaSJIG

I will have a look later.

I have edited my answer and built a sample.

Restructure your component to have only the MudTable in it - no tabs or something else is not possible , the requirement is  when the user clicks on the tab it shows the rows of data.

I mean, you can have the tabs but not in the same component. You should built one component A only with the MudTable and another component B which contains the Tabs and adding component A to this tabs.

My link to the solution is by the way with tabs in it. its just a minimal working sample.

https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/ckcoErFlnholsDle

I added one sample of code . Its almost working for dynamic table. The Issue I found is when the user click on the header for sorting Its not  working for the first time. Also the multiple clicks on the certain  columns does not render the rows properly. The ordering  is wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

I think your snippet is working as expected. Keep in mind, that there are three states of sorting: asc, desc and unsorted. And your first click on the processName column leeds to a sorting for asc, which is already in place. So sorting works, but nothing changes because its alreay sorted asc. And to disable your third sort state "unsorted" just set: <MudTable AllowUnsorted="false"

So actually everything should work now. I have added the AllowUnsorted Option to my answer. If this solved your problem, feel free to accept it :)

And your first click on the processName column leads to a sorting for asc, which is already in place.  Can we  override this , The QA will report it as  a bug , the sorting should work  on the first click , if the records are in asc order , then the first click should order it to  desc and vice versa .

I don´t think so. How should you know how your data is sorted? It randomly is already sorted asc. You still see the arrow down. But the data is not changing because it was already sorted. In a real world scenario, that will  maybe never happen.

How  can we use this for related  data and  multiselection?
